# How to view/change the installation of R that RStudio uses?

Tags: r, rstudio

After installing either anaconda or jupyter, RStudio now shows some logs when installing packages, which indicate it's using R installed by *anaconda*, rather than the *original* version I had installed.

This is not a problem, until I try to install various packages, and I get some maze of frustrating c++ issues (due to graph dependencies).

#### What I've tried so far

- Changed `.libPaths()` from the anaconda path to the default locations (but this doesn't help for R, only for R libraries)

#### Question

How can I tell which R installation RStudio is using, and how do I change it (from the anaconda version, back to the vanilla R version I previously had installed)

Comment: It's in the options/settings somewhere

Answer (score 1):

If you type version in the Rstudio console window it will tell you which version of R you are using...

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.3                         
year           2020                        
month          02                          
day            29                          
svn rev        77875                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
nickname       Holding the Windsock        
>
```

previous relaeases of R can be found here:
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/

Comment: That’s very handy, but suppose I have many of the same version of R binaries located across different locations on my Mac, it doesn’t tell me precisely which one RStudio is using

Comment: Could you change/break the path to each binary in turn and see if that "breaks" RStudio

Comment: Could do, but easier still could move/rename them. I suspect there will be some way to do it with code, just not sure how yet.. (upvote for the help thought)

Answer (score 0):

To those still searching for an answer and stumbled here

As listed above, basic info on the current R version is found entering this in the console of your RStudio

```
version
```

To view which R version is being used:

```
R.home() #tells you the R working directory
RSTUDIO_WHICH_R #tells you the source location of the R instance being used
```

Changing the version of R being used is much trickier. Consulting [the official documentation](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-the-RStudio-Desktop-IDE) can help, but realistically its easiest on Windows and a hassle on Mac/Linux. There might be some sneakier issues with Mac/Linux profiles and config variables, detailed more [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/at-wits-end-trying-to-get-rstudio-to-use-a-different-r-version-plz-help/131383)

Best of luck!